# Bootstrap Modal not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am having an issue with a modal not showing up when the button is clicked in IE8 (and IE7). I've tried removing the "fade" class like i've read in other posts, but it hasn't helped.

Here is a link to the example site, the modal button is in the footer: http://69.195.124.91/~howellc1/riverside2/index.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">SUBMIT STORY</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Share Your Story</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form class="contact" name="contact">
        <label class="label col-sm-10" for="name">Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="input-xlarge col-sm-10"><br>
        <label class="label col-sm-10" for="email">E-mail</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge col-sm-10"><br>
        <label class="label col-sm-10" for="message">Story</label><br>
        <textarea name="message" class="input-xlarge col-sm-12 pb15"></textarea><br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <div id="thanks"></div>
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```